# Why ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream not the same content?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a big problem during one of my unit tests in Java. I compare a byte array with an InputStream and I do not get the same result.

The example is below.

```
public final class ByteGetInputStreamExampleProblem
{
    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        final SecureRandom s = new SecureRandom() ;

        final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;

        long bPut = 0 ;

        final byte[] buffer = new byte[ 2 ] ;

        while( bPut < 10 )
        {
            s.nextBytes( buffer ) ;
            bos.write( buffer ) ;
            bPut += buffer.length ;
        }

        final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( bos.toByteArray() ) ;

        System.out.print("A = ");

        for( int i = 0 ; i < bos.size() ; i++ )
            System.out.print( bos.toByteArray()[i] + ";" ) ;

        System.out.print("\nB = ");

        int c ;
        while( ( c = is.read() ) != -1 )
            System.out.print(c + ":");
    } ;
} ;
```

---

**Output:**

A = -3;-47;-121;37;-73;83;109;-54;20;106;

B = 253:209:135:37:183:83:109:202:20:106:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print the contents of A you print them as bytes. So it will print values between `Byte.MIN_VALUE` up to `Byte.MAX_VALUE` (`-128` to `127`).

When you use `is.read()` you read the contents as a unsigned number passed to you as a `int`. This value will be between `0` and `255`.

You could get the same outputs by casting `c` to a byte, e.g.

```
while( ( c = is.read() ) != -1 ){
    byte b = (byte)c;
    System.out.print(b + ":");
}
```

In essence you will either need to convert both numbers to be between `0` and `255` or between `-128` and `127`.

You can convert the `0` to `255` range to the `-128` to `127` by casting it to a byte.

You can convert the `-128` to `127` by doing `value & 0xFF`. This changes it to be within the `0`-`255` range.

The code for `read()` in the `ByteArrayInputStream` is as follows:

```
public synchronized int read() {
    return (pos < count) ? (buf[pos++] & 0xff) : -1;
}
```